# Getting UIImage size when Image is picked from Photo Library

Tags: iphone

In my application I am uploading the image picked from Photo library. before uploading I need to show the size of image so that user will come to know how much data he need to transfer over network.

To Achive this I need to get Image size , I tried with UIImagePNGRepresentation,after this I am getting size in terms of some MBs,but when I dump image with data received from UIImagePNGRepresentation,size is shown in some KBs. why this is happening?

Does iOS internally compress the image data? how to get image path when picking image from photo library?

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Comment: Yes. iOS doing some compression of image data when we sending image using mail service.

Comment: @Mitesh Khatri, you could probably add this as an answer.